# Better fit w/ Polyfit

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit some data but with the polynomial i can't find a good solution. So, how can I draw a curve like the black one (knowing the type of the curve)?

[image]

```
figure('Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [100 100 500 375]);
hold on;

ydata_s = [1.0e-03 0.5804 0.3916 0.2234 0.1527 0.0697 0];
ydata_m = [0.2765 0.2760 0.2758 0.2757 0.2755 0.2754];
xdata_m = [1 2.5 5 10 50 100];

% Fit with a line.
coeffs = polyfit(xdata_m, ydata_m, 2)
% Define the range where we want the line
xFitting = (0:1:100); 
yFitted = polyval(coeffs, xFitting);

hFit = line(xFitting, yFitted);
hE   = errorbar(xdata_m, ydata_m, ydata_s);


set(hFit                          , ...
  'Color'           , [0 .2 .6]    );
set(hE                            , ...
  'LineStyle'       , 'none'      , ...
  'Marker'          , '.'         , ...
  'Color'           , [.8 .3 .3]  );

hTitle  = title ('Precisione / Velocità');
hXLabel = xlabel('Campionamnto [%]');
hYLabel = ylabel('Funzione Obiettivo [€/P]');

xlim([0 100]);

hLegend = legend( ...
  [hE, hFit], ...
  'Data (\mu \pm \sigma)' , ...
  'Fit (\it{x^3})'      , ...
  'location', 'NorthEast' );

set(gca,'XTick',[1 2.5 5 10 50 100]);
```

Comment: That looks like an exponential decay. You should state what you've tried in more detail.

Comment: Looks like! Is there a way to fit with an exponential curve w/o changing the axis scale?

Comment: The multiexponential fit in a posted answer is one way to "change the axis scale" if by that you mean accounting for the fact that the decay does not go to y=0. In any case, why it does not should be answered in terms of plausible models. Mathematically, it appears that that model might be as simple as an exponential + offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relativity easy if you have the curve fitting toolbox

```
x = [1 2.5 5 10 50 100];
y = [0.2765 0.2760 0.2758 0.2757 0.2755 0.2754];
plot(x, y, '*');
hold('on');
plot(fit(x', y', 'exp2'));
legend({'Data', 'Fit'})
```

[image: Figure of data and fit]

A two term exponential fit has an r^2 of 0.96